# Installing docker without hypervisor Microsoft Windows 10 Professional

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

After installing Docker tools from 
https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox 
unable to start Docker after restart. Always come with Pop-Up Box Unable to start Hypervisor. There is no option to activate Hypervisor in Laptop BIOS setup in the new HP Pro Book. Also try boot2docker same error message.

Comment: I think I found my answer here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#/what-to-know-before-you-install ("Note: If your system does not satisfy these requirements, you can install Docker Toolbox, which uses Oracle Virtual Box instead of Hyper-V.")

Comment: For your information when you have only 4GB RAM try to open docker settings and minimize as it possible. Otherwise it's impossible to run docker.